# Principal Ideal($U$) of $a \in R$ of a commutative ring without unity is { $ra + na | n \in \mathbb{Z} ,r \in R$ }

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I understand $n.a \in U,\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$ 
For a ring with unity Ra is a principal ideal 
Now that this ring does not contain unity $Ra$ does not contain $a$ and
hence not the principal ideal of $a$ 
This is the reason, I believe we are adding $na$ to $ra$ in $\{ ra+na \}$ 
But even $ U1$ = { $ra$ } $\cup$ $a$ which is a smaller set contains a.
Why is it that we need to take $+na$ in the definition?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "I understand $n.a \in U,\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$  How do we know $\forall a \in R$ , $n.a\in Ra $". You don't know that. In fact in general it is false. Why would you care about that, though? The definition you're working with is $(a)=\mathbb Za+Ra$.

Comment: Hope its coherent now. The question being wrong was part of the answer xP

Comment: @PhalakshaCG yes, it's better.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question

Since $U$ is also a subring 
$\implies \forall a\in U, n.a \in U$
$\therefore U=\{ ra + na\} $ Hence, $U$ has to contain all $na$ if it needs to contain $a$